# Can 杠杆 ("lever") be used for levers which operate mechanisms (e.g. "pull the lever, Kronk")?

Tags: meaning, word

> [CC-CEDICT](https://www.mdbg.net/chinese/dictionary?wdqb=%E6%9D%A0%E6%9D%86): 杠杆 (gàng​gǎn​): lever / pry bar / crowbar / financial leverage

In English there are two types of [lever](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/lever), one which pivots via a fulcrum and is used for raising objects...

> [image: Image of bearded man raising sphere via the use of a lever]
> <sub>Image Source: [Wikimedia Commons](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Archimedes%27-Lever.png)</sub>

...and another which operates some kind of mechanism, such as in a hilarious scene from [*The Emperor's New Groove*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Emperor%27s_New_Groove):

> [image: "Pull the lever Kronk... wrong leveeeeeer!" "Why do we even have that lever?"]

I'm not sure if the Chinese 杠杆 can take on this second meaning.

**Question**: Can 杠杆 ("lever") be used for levers which operate mechanisms?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A lever using leverage to lift an object is called "杠杆" (pry bar)

A lever for operating mechanisms is called "操纵杆" (control stick/operating lever)

A joystick is also a "操纵杆" (for game control)

扳机/ 扳杆 (trigger/ lever) that only move in two directions is what we see in that scene

Answer (score 1):

I think the second one is more referred to as 把手/手柄 (handle) or 机关/扳机 (trigger). I never hear people call that a 杠杆. 杠杆 only means the first one, which is some mechanism that magnifies force, including abstract ones like in finance.

Comment: The most common usage of 把手/手柄 is "door handle" (门把手). Not all door handle can be turned.

Comment: @TangHo I am not disagreeing with that. But as I see the picture provided by the OP, if I translate that I would say 拉那个把手。不，不是那个把手！呃。到底是为了什么我们会有那个把手？

Comment: That is why I said "not all",  meaning some 把手/手柄 do move and function as operating lever. Some door handles can be turned to open the door lock